# How many pairs of primes $p$ and $q$ are there such that $p − q = 3$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-verification

How many pairs of primes $p$ and $q$ are there such that $p − q = 3$?

Then we have $$p=q+3$$ But, $2$ is the only even prime (if not would not be prime). If $5,2$ were not the only then $$p=(2n+1) + 3$$ for some odd integer $2n+1$. This gives $$2n+1+3=2n+4=2(n+2)$$ so that is an even number rather than a prime. Just a little feedback on if this looks correct.

Comment: Yes that is fine... you could just state that the difference between odd primes is even and two is the only even prime.

Comment: Correct. You have completed a "proof by contradicion".

Comment: You could add a line after "$p=q+3$" to say explicitly that one of the primes must be even.

Comment: p-q=odd  so one of them is odd  ,and other is even .  but the only even prime number is 2 , so p-2=3 ,p=5